# Any suggestions for improving my fitting?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, distributions

This is not a completely *Mathematica* question, but I hope people who are familiar both with *Mathematica* and statistics could help me on this.

I have a set of data as

```
data = {{0, 0.046}, {40, 0.111}, {80, 0.291}, {120, 0.808}, {160, 1.742}, {200, 3.319}, {240, 5.017}, {280, 5.503}, {320, 5.897}}
```

The data seems to follow a logistic curve, thus for fitting, we can write:

```
F = NonlinearModelFit[data, A/(1 + E^(-(t - t0)/b)), {{A, 1}, {t0, 50}, {b, 10}}, t];
F["ParameterTable"]
```

Here is the result:

[image]

which is not bad, but I would like to improve it. Any suggestions here?

One thing the came to my head is to use inverse variances as weights. Standard deviations are given as

```
sd = {0.003, 0.012, 0.023, 0.056, 0.083, 0.216, 0.526, 0.366, 0.313}
```

thus, we have

```
F = NonlinearModelFit[data, A/(1 + E^(-(t - t0)/b)), {{A, 1}, {t0, 50}, {b, 10}}, t, Weights -> 1/sd^2];
F["ParameterTable"]
```

still, the results are not very satisfactory. Is there any other way to improve my fitting?

Comment: Looking at the plot, I think the curve fits pretty nicely to your datapoints. What exactly makes you think that the results are "not very satisfactory"? Which parameter are you considering?

Comment: @Domen Thanks for your comment. The logistic rate of the plot, $1/b$, is $0.028$. I expected to be higher, for example, between $0.030$ and $0.035$, based on the expectations from the underlying mechanisms. I thought, perhaps, one could alter the logistic fitting to reproduce the mentioned values!

Comment: By using ``Manipulate[Show[ListPlot[Around[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ Transpose[{data, sd}]], Plot[A/(1 + E^(-(t - t0)*b1)), {t, 0, 400}]], {{A, 6.26}, 4, 8}, {{t0, 197.7}, 160, 200}, {{b1, .025}, 0.02, 0.04}]`` and manually varying the parameters, you can see why $0.03$ gives a worse fit. This is even more pronounced if you use ``ListLogPlot`` and ``LogPlot``, where the growth rate coincides with the slope of the line in the exponential phase of the growth (of course, using logarithmic plots can be a bit misleading, because the residuals are not equally scaled, but still).

Comment: @Domen Many thanks for the above code, which is really helpful. Just a question: Could please elaborate how can I use ListLogPot and LogPlot for my data?

Comment: In the code I posted, replace ``ListPlot`` with ``ListLogPlot``, and ``Plot`` with ``LogPlot``.

Comment: @Domen Another question: If I use the LogPlot that you suggested, it seems $0.025$ is a better fit than $0.028$ obtained in my post. Which one do you think is a correct result? The interesting thing is that, if one adds the inverse variances as weights, one obtains the rate as $0.025$. How can one justify this?

Comment: "I expected it to be higher."  Data has a terrible habit of not following theoretical results.  If you don't believe the data, why would you think the fit can be improved?

Comment: @JimB Thanks for your comment. I have learned a lot from you by  searching in this website. In fact, I was forcing the problem to reproduce the desired result!! A question: The plot that I have presented in my post, has a logistic growth rate of $0.028$. If I use, instead, LogPlot, it seems that $0.025$ is a better fit. What do you suggest to be a correct result? Interestingly, if one considered the inverse variances as weights, one also obtain the logistic growth rate as $0.025$.

Comment: The "theory" should not only suggest the structure of the model but also the structure of the "errors".  For example, should the error be additive on the original data scale or additive on the log scale?  (It is common on this site - and others - to be oblivious about the error structure.)

Comment: @JimB In my case, the errors are: the standard deviations to be divided by $\sqrt{3}$. That would be great if you could elaborate in both cases that you mentioned, how I can include the errors. Many many thanks!

Comment: Having the standard deviations divided by anything makes no sense.  But taking the logs does result in the residuals looking a bit better.  Without taking logs, the errors tend to increase with increasing values of the response variable.  I'll add a more informative answer/response later today.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for your reply. I said the division by $\sqrt{3}$, as I thought perhaps, because the values reported in my post are means, and the number of measurements are $3$, perhaps the errors should be: standard deviation/ $\sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 2):

In your comments you mention that the responses are means of 3 values.  If the response you're really interested in is the mean of 3 values, then we're ready to go.  If the response should be the individual values and you really have a repeated measures design, then you should use something other than *Mathematica*.  The functions `LinearModelFit` and `NonlinearModelFit` are just fine for simple models (with "simple" meaning just one error term).

To fit $k$ just replace $1/b$ with $k$.  The underlying model that `NonlinearModelFit` thinks it's estimating is for the $i$-th observation

$$y_i=\frac{a}{e^{-k (t_i-t_0)}+1}+\epsilon_i$$

where $y_i$ is the response, $a$, $k$, and $t_0$ are parameters to be estimated, $t$ is the predictor variable and $\epsilon_i$ has a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$.

```
nlm1 = NonlinearModelFit[data, a/(1 + E^(-k (t - t0))), {{a, 1}, {t0, 50}, {k, 0.1}}, t];
nlm1["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable"]
```

[image: Parameter confidence interval table]

We see that your desired 0.30 value for $k$ is included in the 95% confidence interval.

A plot of the predicted response vs the residuals suggests that the error term is incorrectly structured in that the variability seems to increase with an increase in predicted response.

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{nlm1["PredictedResponse"], nlm1["FitResiduals"]}]]
```

[image: Predicted response vs residual]

You also considered taking the logs of the responses.

```
data2 = data;
data2[[All, 2]] = Log[data2[[All, 2]]];
nlm2 = NonlinearModelFit[data2, Log[a/(1 + E^(-k (t - t0)))], {{a, 1}, {t0, 50}, {k, 0.1}}, t];
nlm2["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable"]
```

[image: Parameter confidence interval table for log transform]

Note that your desired 0.30+ value for $k$ is *not* within a much tighter 95% confidence interval.

The residual plot doesn't display the increase in variability as before which suggests meeting the model assumptions better than the other model.  In other words, this model provides a better fit to the data.  It just doesn't provide a fit that coincides with your desires.

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{nlm2["PredictedResponse"], nlm2["FitResiduals"]}]]
```

[image: Residual plot from log transform]

The data should really be analyzed according to how it was collected. And if the 3 values that constitute the means are available, that's what should be used in an analysis.  But while one can use *Mathematica* to do so, that would entail a bit of programming as opposed to using `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: Many thanks! A question: you concluded that your second model is a better fit. Now, if we consider the inverse variances as weights, we can reproduce the values of $k$ and the confidence interval that you obtained in your second model. So, can one say in this way we can incorporate the errors?

Comment: If the weights are all the same value as you mentioned before ($1/\sqrt{3}$), then that won't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the error in the data is essentially zero, you are better off with Monotonic-Interpolation in a case like this. The whole point of Interpolation is that the function you get goes exactly through each data point.

```
data=data={{0,0.046},{40,0.111},{80,0.291},{120,0.808},{160,1.742},
{200,3.319},{240,5.017},{280,5.503},{320,5.897}};
f=ResourceFunction["MonotonicInterpolation"][data];
Plot[f[t],{t,0,320},Epilog->{AbsolutePointSize@4,Point@data}]
```

[image: plot]
If you want a closed form for the above function, use the next line.

```
pw[t_] = ResourceFunction["InterpolatingFunctionToPiecewise"][f, t]
```

[image]

For more on the functions used above see documentation [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MonotonicInterpolation) and [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/InterpolatingFunctionToPiecewise/).

Similar to MonotonicInterpolation there are ResourceFunctions [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/AkimaInterpolation/), [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/GeneralizedAkimaInterpolation/), and [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CubicMonotonicInterpolation/) that run faster on large datasets, but MonotonicInterpolation used above gives a smoother function.

***** UPDATE *****

Next I show how to find the maximum of the derivative of f[t] above.

```
Plot[f'[t],{t,0,320}]
```

[image: graphic]
Use a smaller PlotRange and it is clear the maximum of f'[t] is between 200 and 213. Look at the Piecewise function pw[t] defined above, and we see the interval from 200 to 213 is one piece of pw[t] and Simplify gives us that piece below.

```
poly=Simplify[pw[t],200<t<213]
```

[image: cubic-polynomial]
Now we can find the maximum of the derivative of the above polynomial.

```
FindMaximum[D[poly,t],t]
```

[image: maximum]
So in the plot of f'[t] above, the maximum derivative is at {t,f'[t]}={0.04799,207.91}

Comment: Wow, I never heard of this! Please let me time to understand your approach. Just two initial questions: I need to read off the "growth rate" from the curve. In your fitted curve, how can I do this? Another question is: So, in your approach you have not whatsoever taken into account the errors, correct?

Comment: @Aneternalstudent for the growth rate you'd just take the derivative of that giant polynomial. For the peak growth rate you'd want to maximize it.

Comment: @flinty Thanks for your comment. You mean that, first I take derivative of say $f$ with respect to $t$ and then use FindRoot to obtain the solutions of $f' = 0$?

Comment: Any of the algorithms I mention as well as the Interpolation that Mathematica has built-in will return a function that perfectly passes through the data points. You could say I am assuming the errors are zero. However, if you want to nudge the curve in a certain direction, you can simply modify the data you pass to MonotonicInterpolation. That would give you a hand-wavy way of getting a smooth function that does whatever you want. As suggested by other comments, you can simply compute the derivative of the function that MonotonicInterpolation returns.

Comment: Is this not likely a case of overfitting?  Why would you not consider that there might be some measurement error?  But wait...I see you start with an assumption that there is no error.  Still...that seems extremely unlikely.

Comment: @TedErsek I couldn't completely understand how to calculate the growth rate. For example, in the Wikipedia for the logistic function: $L /( 1+ e^{-k(x-x_0)})$, it says $k$ is the growth rate, but I don't know how one can obtain this.

Comment: @JimB That would be great if you could elaborate on your approach.

Comment: (1) The measured data could have four decimal places of precision. We all know that any Interpolation method is a way to get a good approximation for what happens between the samples. For the purpose of obtaining an approximate function, you  may want to ignore that there is measurement error as I did. ******(2)  If you use any sort of interpolation (mine or any other type) the result you get has nothing to do with the logistic function or any other model. If you need to use that logistic function, you should use a curve-fit of a logistic model. That was done in the original question.

Comment: @TedErsek I got your point. I was asking how to find the intrinsic growth rate of your model. I was saying in the logistic curve $k$ is the intrinsic rate, but if we look at the plot of the derivative of the function to see where it is maximized, the value is $k L/4$. By making this analogy, I was asking how to find the intrinsic growth rate of your model? In other words, if we look at the plot of the derivative of your function, the maximum is not exactly the intrinsic rate. I hope I could make my point clear. It would be great if you could also make a comment on the growth rate in youranswer

Comment: @Aneternalstudent no setting the derivative to zero and finding the root finds a local maximum/minimum of the function, not the maximum of its derivative. You want to maximize the derivative. `deriv = D[pw[t], t]; NMaximize[deriv, t]` returns `{0.0479928, {t -> 207.908}}` - and you can see this slope here like this: `Show[
 Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 320}], Graphics[InfiniteLine[{207.908, f[207.908]}, {1, 0.0479927}]]]`

Comment: @flinty Thanks for your comment. Yesterday, I figured it out. My problem is, that perhaps you can help is: In the case of logistic function, $L / (1 + e^{-k (x - x_0)})$, people call $k$ as the growth rate. However, this values is not the value of maximized derivative. I'm looking how I can obtain similar quantity for the above complicated polynomial.

Comment: @An eternal student, I don't have extensive knowledge of statistics, but I added steps where I find the maximum of the derivative of my interpolating function.

Comment: Any idea what could be the problem when you get "QuadraticOptimization::ubnd: The problem is unbounded."? Which I get for for example the data: `data={{0.05263157895, 0.1109743176}, {0.1052631579, 
  0.2455264212}, {0.3157894737, 0.6177956854}, {0.4736842105, 
  0.7101270479}, {0.5263157895, 0.7400515762}, {0.5789473684, 
  0.7704164327}, {0.7368421053, 0.8597512263}, {0.8947368421, 
  0.9425805269}, {0.9473684211, 0.9727999966}, {0.9684210526, 
  0.98359786}}`.